# I want my back to top icon appear only after i scroll the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had made back to top icon which works as it should be but the problem is it appears when i open the page but i want back to top to be appeared only after i scroll page.Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please post you code to reproduce the issue. You can use https://jsfiddle.net/ for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    toggleBackToTop();
  });
  
  // Show and hide back to top button 
  function toggleBackToTop() {
    var offset = 1, // Offset position when to show
        scrollTop = 0,
        $btn = $('.back-to-top');
    
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    if(scrollTop >= offset) {
        $btn.fadeIn();
    } else {
      $btn.fadeOut();
    }
    
  }
})();
```

Note: Update, your button selector

For Referance:

> Output: http://output.jsbin.com/nojese
>
> Code: http://jsbin.com/nojese/edit?html,css,js